# Scoping resource routes in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, scope

I have a `resources :shops`

which results in a `/shops`, `/shops/:id`, etc

I know I can scope collection or members with

```
resources :shops do
  scope ":city" do
   # collection and members
  end
end
```

or do it before with

```
scope ":city" do
 resources :shops
end
```

But I can't figure out how to make the route be on all members (including the standard REST ones) and collection, like so

```
/shops/:city/

/shops/:city/:id
```

Comment: You want routes like `/shops/:city/:id` etc?

Comment: yeah, so everytime the shops route is being worked with, it will always have a :city scope

Comment: Seems non-standard. Can you explain your use case?

Comment: I don't mind changing stuff around. Basically, I have a bunch of Shops which have a city attribute. I want to scope the shops only on a certain city and to reflect that in a route. So, if using friendly_id, /shops/new-york/joes-dinner and /shops/los-angeles/joes-dinner would result in different shop pages. I don't mind creating a city model if thats needed

Answer (score 1):

As per your [**use case**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25097276/scoping-resource-routes-in-rails-4?noredirect=1#comment39053474_25097276) and question, you are trying to have logically wrong routes. You have shops within the city, NOT city within the shop.

Firstly you should normalize your database. You should create another table `cities` and replace your `city` attributes with `city_id` in `shops` table.

You need `has_many` and `belongs_to` association between `cities` and `shops`.

```
# Models
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shops
  ... # other stuff
end

class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
  ... # other stuff
end
```

Routes

```
resources :cities do
  resources :shops
end
```

It will generate routes like:

```
               POST     /cities/:city_id/shops(.:format)          shops#create
new_city_shop  GET      /cities/:city_id/shops/new(.:format)      shops#new
edit_city_shop GET      /cities/:city_id/shops/:id/edit(.:format) shops#edit
    city_shop  GET      /cities/:city_id/shops/:id(.:format)      shops#show
               PATCH    /cities/:city_id/shops/:id(.:format)      shops#update
               PUT      /cities/:city_id/shops/:id(.:format)      shops#update
               DELETE   /cities/:city_id/shops/:id(.:format)      shops#destroy
```

Logically, these routes will show that in which city the particular shop exists.

Comment: that would seem ok, is there a way to lose the /cities/ prefix?

Comment: Why you want to do this? I prefer don't to do this.. this is the way that how we have rest routes.. as of security reasons, you can modify your `id` using `friendly_id`

Answer (score 0):

**Namespace**

You may wish to consider including a [`namespace`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Since you're trying to pull up the `cities` for shops (IE I imagine you want to show shops in `Sao Paulo`), you'd be able to do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
namespace :shops do
   resources :cities, path: "", as: :city, only: [:index] do #-> domain.com/shops/:id/
      resources :shops, path: "", only: [:show] #-> domain.com/shops/:city_id/:id
   end
end
```

This will allow you to create a separate controller:

```
#app/controllers/shops/cities_controller.rb
Class Shops::CitiesController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @city = City.find params[:id]
   end
end

#app/controllers/shops/shops_controller.rb
Class Shops::ShopsController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @city = City.find params[:city_id]
      @shop = @city.shops.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

This will ensure you're able to create the routing structure you need. The namespace does two important things -

> 1. Ensures you have the correct routing structure
> 2. Separates your controllers